# Correcting the code in python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in programming in python. In [this question in codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-qzsCL/1/1?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096), I need to:

> Write a function average that returns the average value of a list filled only with numbers.

Here is the list:

```
lloyd = {
"name": "Lloyd", 
"homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0], 
"quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0], 
"tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}

alice = {
"name": "Alice",
"homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
"quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
"tests": [89.0, 97.0]
} 

tyler = {
"name": "Tyler",
"homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
"quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
"tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}
```

Below is my attempt:

```
 students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
 def average(k):
     k = a(students)
     for x[k] in k:
         if x[k] == int:
        return average(k) = sum(x[k]) / len(x[k])
```

I know why `x[k]` does not work, but I cannot think of a solution either.

Comment: what is the line `k = a(students)`?

Comment: average a list filled only with numbers but what you give is a list of dicts.

Comment: Your syntax is all over the place. What is `a`? Why are you trying to *assign* to `average(k)` in a `return` statement (neither of which you can do in Python).

Comment: I don't recall ever making a function `a` while doing this exercise in Codecademy. Then again, it was a while ago. But Codecademy would actually give you a proper name instead of just `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question did not specify what it should return if argument is not a list with only numbers.
I assume you want some lenient version that will return passed in argument if it does not fulfill that criterium.

**tweaked**:

```
import numbers, operator
def average( what ):
    if not isinstance( what, list ):
        return what
    if not all( isinstance(item, numbers.Number) for item in what ):
        return what
    if len(what) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return operator.truediv( sum( what ), len( what ) )
```

Old one:

```
def average( what ):
    if not isinstance( what, list ):
        return what
    if len(what) == 0:
        return None
    if not all( isinstance(item, (int, long, float, complex)) for item in what ):
        return what
    else:
        return sum( what ) / len( what )
```

[ideone working sample](http://ideone.com/EcY0BH)

Also see what Mr E wrote about integers (my version might surprise you for list of ints).

Comment: How about: `if isinstance(what, list) and all(isinstance(el, numbers.Number) for el in what): return operator.truediv(sum(what), len(what))`

Comment: @Jon Clements, still prefer two ifs for readability, other than that I simply didn't know about those solutions :)